# Наречия качественные и образа действия

Tags: наречия, морфология

> Он *бережно* размял колос в ладонях.
>
> Он *ползком* передвинулся поближе к
> воде. Он *насухо* вытер котелок.

Мой учебник говорит, что наречие *бережно* является наречием качественным, а наречия *ползком* и *трепетно* -- образа действия.

Я плохо ощущаю разницу между ними. Почему наречие *бережно* -- качественное, а *ползком* -- образа действия. Звучат, будто принадлежат к одной категории: я делаю что-то *ползком* или я делаю что-то *бережно*.

Можете объяснить как точнее их различать?

А наречия *по-ребячьи* и *ничком* я даже не знаю к какой из этих категорий отнести.

> Он *по-ребячьи* потянул ладонь.
>
> Убитый лежал *ничком*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что размять колос в ладонях можно как *более бережно*, так и *менее бережно* — вот вам и качественное наречие. А вот *более ползком* и *менее ползком* передвинуться нельзя — это не качественное наречие.

Answer (score 3):

ФОРМАЛЬНО качественные наречия образуются от качественных прилагательных, причем только эти наречия имеют степень сравнения: тихо - тише, весело - веселее.

С точки зрения СЕМАНТИКИ качественное наречие характеризует качество (внутреннее свойство) действия или другого признака.

Он бережно размял колос в ладонях. Действие совершается аккуратно, без резких движений. Это качество.

Он ползком передвинулся поближе к воде. Ползком - способ действия, качество для движения - это, например, скорость (быстро или медленно).

Он быстро и насухо вытер котелок. Быстро - качество, насухо - результат.

Вообще на вопрос как? отвечают определительные наречия, среди которых выделяют качественные, количественные (очень,  весьма, крайне, много, чуть-чуть), способа и образа действия (вплавь), сравнения и уподобления (по-ребячьи). Остальные наречия относятся к обстоятельственным.

Answer (score 3):

```
     Мой учебник говорит, что наречие бережно является наречием качественным, 
      а наречия    ползком и трепетно - образа действия.
```

Вы ничего не перепутали? Трепетно - тоже качественное, т.к. образовано от качественного прилагательного (Чувство его какое? трепетное, (каково?) трепетно ), имеет степень сравнения: Стал относиться как? - ещё трепетнее. Это качество действия, как и бережно. Здесь ассоциация с трепетным действием.

Определительные наречия образа или способа действия характеризуют не само действие, а то, как оно совершается. Например: вдребезги, пешком, на ощупь, вплавь врукопашную и др. 
Образ или способ действия может быть определен путем сравнения или уподобления:

Он по-ребячьи потянул ладонь.

Обозначение способа действия совмещается здесь с его качественной характеристикой, поэтому Вы и засомневались.

Убитый лежал ничком. - определительное наречие образа действия, потому что у него нет степени сравнения.

Итак, определительное  качественное наречие имеет степень сравнения или это местоимение с корнем КАК (кое-как, как-нибудь);

определительное количественное обозначает меру и степень качества (относится к качественному наречию или  заменяет сочетание с ним) - очень весело, идёт еле-еле = очень медленно;

определительное наречие образа или способа действия характеризует, каким способом производится действие, у него не может быть степени сравнения.